# c programming (cs50) - long not working for credit card numbers on my local machine

Tags: c, cs50

im new to C but im aware long is usually used for longer integers such as credit card numbers. im doing credit from the cs50 week 1 (https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/1/credit/), and the program is able to run on the cs50 codespace but not on my local one.

could it be possible that my compiler is not configured correctly? othwise what else cld be the reason? when i enter the credit card number, my local machine js keeps prompting me until i reduce the length of numbers, unlike in the codespace where it works perfectly fine.

i have attached my code below, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

// gcc credit.c -o credit cs50.c
// .\credit

int main(void)
{
    /* GET CARD NUMBER > 0 */
    long card;
    do
    {
        card = get_long("Enter card number: ");
    }
    while (card < 0);

    /* COUNT LENGTH */
    long cardlength = card;
    int count = 0;
    while (cardlength > 1)
    {
        cardlength = cardlength / 10;
        count++;
    }

    /* CHECK FOR VALID LENGTH */

    /* CALCULATE CHECKSUM */
    long cardnumber = card;
    int singlesum = 0;
    int doubledsum = 0;
    int last = 0;
    int last2nd = 0;
    int last2ndL = 0;
    int last2ndR = 0;
    int totalsum = 0;

    while (cardnumber > 0)
    {
        // remove last digit and add to singlesum
        last = cardnumber % 10;
        cardnumber /= 10;
        singlesum += last;

        // remove 2nd last digit and add INDIVIDUAL DIGITS to doubledsum
        last2nd = (cardnumber % 10) * 2;
        cardnumber /= 10;
        last2ndR = last2nd % 10;
        last2ndL = last2nd / 10;
        doubledsum += last2ndR + last2ndL;
    }

    totalsum = singlesum + doubledsum;

    /* CHECK FOR LUKE ALG */
    if (totalsum % 10 != 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 0; // means program run successfully, terminate with main 
    }

    /* GET FIRST 2 DIGITS */
    long firsttwo = card;
    while (firsttwo > 100)
    {
        firsttwo = firsttwo / 10;
    }

    /* CHECK FOR FORMATTING OF 3 TYPES */
    if ((firsttwo / 10 == 3) && (firsttwo % 10 == 4 || firsttwo % 10 == 7) && (count == 15))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }

    else if ((firsttwo / 10 == 5) && (firsttwo % 10 > 0 && firsttwo % 10 < 6) && (count == 16))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }

    else if ((firsttwo / 10 == 4) && (count == 16 || count == 13))
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

}

// amex = 15 digits, start with 34 or 37
// mastercard = 16 digits, start with 51, 52, 53, 54, 55
// visa = 13 or 16 digits, starts with 4
```

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? `long` is the same size as `int` there. Try `long long` instead or `int64_t`.

Comment: Have you typed `"[cs50] credit card"` into the search box at the top of the page -- many, many answers on the topic already. (hint - read and treat the digits as text...)

Comment: Credit card numbers are not integers and you can't store them in an integer type. They are strings.

Comment: OT: `while (firsttwo > 100)` would happily leave you with `100` as a two digit value. You probably mean `while (firsttwo > 99)`...

Comment: @RetiredNinja "long is the same size as int there.  (Windows)." --> the size of a `long` is a compiler issue.  It is influenced by the OS, but not define by the OS.

Answer (score 2):

C specifies `long`  as having a range needing *at least* 32-bits.  Some implementations use a wider `long` employing 64-bit.

OP's code relies on `long` as 64-bit and so fails to perform as desired on systems with 32-bit `long`.

Use `long long` which is *at least* 64-bit and can encode all 17 decimal digits values.

```
//long card;
//...
//  card = get_long("Enter card number: ");

long long card;
...
  card = get_long_long("Enter card number: ");
```

---

**Other**

Loop while >= 100

```
// while (firsttwo >= 100)
while (firsttwo > 100)
```

Comment: If you can't do math on it, it's not a number, and shouldn't be stored that way (or someone might accidentally try, or hit range issues like the question asker, or invert it, etc.). This goes for credit card numbers, phone numbers, license plate numbers (those "numbers" even have letters in them!), and much more.